# MonoDevelop android - no emulators listed (Windows XP)?

Tags: android, windows, monodevelop, xamarin.android

Just installed MonoDevelop for Android 2.8.6.5 on Windows XP.

When I try to run the project there are no emulators showing up in the emulator list.

Any ideas why?

Comment: Now I can see the devices. I moved the .android\avd folder to my Documents and Settings\<user> folder. I'm not sure why it was installed somewhere else.


Now the start button is grayed out and nothing happens when I click it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Run-> Select Device**.

You need to select the emulator devices listed and then click on " Start Emulator", it will take a while to start the emulator OR  click "Create Emulator", it  will start AVD manager and select the device and "Start".

After the emulator boots up completely, try
Run->Run With

Hope it helps