# monodevelop helloworld app fail to install

Tags: monodevelop

I installed "monodevelop" IDE tool, Android SDK and other required tools on my windows xp. I started new sample helloworld project. Builds OK. I run this application and emulator comes up OK. But, I get this error when I deploy the application onto my device emulator.

Waiting for packaging processing to complete
Getting package list from device
Installing shared runtime package on device
    pkg: /data/local/tmp/Mono.Android.DebugRuntime-debug.apk
Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_MEDIA_UNAVAILABLE]
91 KB/s (25866358 bytes in 274.882s)
**Failed to install shared runtime package**

I appreciate any help to resolve this issue.

Comment: Hi @an_at_so, I have a similar issue on Windows XP. did you have any problems seeing the devices? I haven't gotten as far as you, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9626848/monodevelop-android-no-emulators-listed-windows-xp

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, first time i gave the same error, the next time i run, it start to install another package. the 4th time i run, it executed successfully. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

One possible cause of this error might be that you don't have enough space on the emulator.