# Failed to install package using Visual Studio C#

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [monodevelop helloworld app fail to install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9637388/monodevelop-helloworld-app-fail-to-install)

I have installed Mono for android full version. and tried to run Sample HelloWorld program in a Physical Device but i am getting error Please Help... In Deploy To Devoice---- Getting package list from device Installing shared runtime package on device pkg:
 Failed to install package>

Comment: There should be more to the error message, perhaps using the More Details link.  That would give us something to work from.